# Infopath ,sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath2010

I have a list in SharePoint 2013 which contain 4 checkbox.I want to calculate the percentage how many checkbox is selected?

I have full control. 
I have access to InfoPath form. 
for example. if 3 checkbox is checked total = 75%

I tried with **avg()** function in InfoPath but it is not working properly. 
it shows correct output when all field is checked otherwise it shows **"NaN"**.

I am not able to set default value of checkboxes to "1" or as Selected.

Comment: Can you share the calculation you have used to output the result? and any other details which you can shrae?

Comment: thanks SigarDave for looking into it .I corrected my mistake. Actually i m using avg function and initially field default value is false. because of that it shows NaN
i know it is basic thing. but thanks again

Comment: Please answer your own question, so that no one need to look it again.